# Who is Sakamoto (In chat room)?

Tags: discussion

In the Chat Room, I notice that when you ask a question it pops up in the Chat Room Maid Cafe and next to it, it has the user "Sakamoto" next to it on the left hand side.

Who is Sakamoto? Is it like the user Community (Like a background process)? I have no idea. Anyone know?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Sakamoto](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/-179/sakamoto) is just a bot that posts from the ["recent questions" RSS feed](https://anime.stackexchange.com/feeds). Any new questions (up to 5 at a time) will be posted by Sakamoto anytime between a few minutes and an hour after being posted.

There are other bots, too: [Hell Butterfly](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/-176/hell-butterfly) (for posting recent meta questions), [Big Shot](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/-246/big-shot) (who I don't think I've ever seen, lol), and [Planet Express Delivery](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/-175/planet-express-delivery) (for posting questions about anime from other sites).

You can see the room's feeds [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/6697/maid-cafe-?tab=feeds).